# What data types can elasticsearch index that can be used with Tire?

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to index and search a boolean field on a model.  However, the only examples I can find of indexing and searching using Tire are on `string` and `date` types.  Where can I find a list of the other types supported by Tire + Elasticsearch, possibly with examples?